# Copy large database from one server to another

Tags: azure-sql-database

I want to copy a database from one server to another. The source database is a geo-replicated read-only secondary. In case it matters, I want to use this as the source to avoid loading up the production (primary) database.
The source and target servers are in different resource groups, but they are located in the same area and in the same subscription.

This might seem like pretty standard stuff, but the problem I am having is that neither the export functionality nor the copy functionality within the Azure portal will work. The export fails with

> Error code 400: the size of the database to be exported is bigger than what is supported for this operation.

The copy fails in a slightly different way; when I try to configure the target database I cannot set the data storage size, it defaults to 32GB and the slider to change it is missing:

[image]

The source database is a little over 1TB in size.
What other options do I have for creating a copy of that database? Or is there a way to work around the error displayed above?

Answer (score 0):

The slide to increase the size should be there. If you don't see maybe your user isn't allowed to take such decision:

[image]

By the way, you said that your database is actually slightly more than 1TB.

In this case you have to move to [Premium P11 or  P15](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-dtu-single-databases#premium-service-tier).

Moving it there will presents some [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-dtu-single-databases#premium-service-tier).